# How do I set my result type to be recent, in tweepy python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to make a twitter bot that retweets the 5 most recent posts in #fortnite on Twitter. The only problem I'm having is how do I set my result type to only be recent posts, so the bot only retweets the recent posts in #Fortnite.

```
import tweepy as twitter
import keys
import time, datetime

auth = twitter.OAuthHandler(keys.API_KEY, keys.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(keys.ACCESS_TOKEN, keys.SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN)
api = twitter.API(auth)


def twitter_bot(hashtag, delay):
  while True:
    print(f"\n{datetime.datetime.now()}\n")

    for tweets in twitter.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=hashtag, count=10).items(5):
      try:
        tweet_id = dict(tweets._json)["id"]
        tweet_text = dict(tweets._json)["text"]

        print("id: " + str(tweet_id))
        print("text: " + str(tweet_text))

        api.retweet(tweet_id)

      except:
        print("error")

    time.sleep(delay)

twitter_bot("#Fortnite", 10)
```

In the Twitter API docs, it says the following -

result_type

Specifies what type of search results you would prefer to receive. The current default is "mixed." Valid values include:

- mixed : Include both popular and real time results in the response.
- recent : return only the most recent results in the response
- popular : return only the most popular results in the response.

Link to docs - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

If you know how to implement this into this code, I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The **result_type** parameter is for the search tweets api, so:

```
import tweepy
import keys
import time, datetime

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.API_KEY, keys.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(keys.ACCESS_TOKEN, keys.SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def twitter_bot(hashtag, delay):
  while True:
    print(f"\n{datetime.datetime.now()}\n")

    for tweets in api.search_tweets(q=hashtag, result_type="recent", count=5):
      try:
        tweet_id = dict(tweets._json)["id"]
        tweet_text = dict(tweets._json)["text"]

        print("id: " + str(tweet_id))
        print("text: " + str(tweet_text))

        api.retweet(tweet_id)

      except:
        print("error")

    time.sleep(delay)

twitter_bot("#Fortnite", 10)
```

Comment: It appears to be retweeting some posts that are not vary recent, is this because twitters API also throws in some from **top posts** too? @Juan